# How to eliminate default build variants in android gradle

Tags: android, gradle

We have already different build variants in our project (dev,qa and others), making the default variants irrelevant and confusing.

Is there a way to completely remove the default build variants, namely `debug` and `release`? They're already generating compiler errors that won't be fixed since they won't be supported anymore. I'd like them to be completely removed from existence.

If that's not possible I'd like to make most tasks that depend on them to be obsolete as if they never existed, like `assembleDebug`, `compileDebugSources`, `installDebug`, `testDebugUnitTest` etc.

It's ok to override a couple of tasks and generate nice error messages, but I'm afraid I'd end up overriding lots of tasks.

Comment: Why don't you just use debug and release instead of two of your custom variant names? It seems like you've complicated things more than you could have.

Comment: They were being misused for ages for things that weren't related to their names and making people confused. It's easier to deprecate technical stuff than to fix people's expectations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting these on build.gradle will make most if not all references to debug variant tasks to disapear.

```
android.variantFilter { variant ->
    if(variant.buildType.name.equals('debug') ) {
        variant.setIgnore(true);
    }
}
```

It's interesting to note though that if you have another variant based on debug it will still work. For example you can still run QA variant if you have it defined this way:

```
buildTypes {
    qa {
        initWith debug
        . . .
```

Comment: any idea as how to do this with `androidComponents.onVariant` api?